# roles variable in role guard is not being read properly

Tags: nestjs

I implemented roles for my angular/nestjs/postgresql application ('Admin' and 'User') and i activated the the role guard for my getuserlist() to be only showable to admin upon login in yet it keeps guarding the list for both admin and user in addition of server getting shut down with the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

`at C:\Users\naceu\Desktop\MyDeveloperHub\projet internat\projet-internat\projet-internat1\backend\src\users\models\roles.guard.ts:23:45`

//I made the guard with the following files :
`//role.enum.ts`
`//role.decorator.ts`
`/role.guard.ts`
//and in the controller file containing the `getuserlist()`
//this is the role.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import Role from './role.enum';
import { ROLES_KEY } from './roles.decorator';
@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const requireRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(), 
    ]);
  
    if (!requireRoles) {
      return true;
    }
    // const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    // return matchRoles(roles, user.roles);
    return requireRoles.some((role) => user.roles.includes(role));
  } 
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong without the full code of User class. I guess when the error produces `following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')` user.roles is undefined.

Comment: i kept searching for the source of the error and it appears to be that the user variable before it (user.roles) was not being red as the user entity so i rebuilt the whole guard again and now it works